# Why do I keep getting a 1215 cannot add foreign key constraint error?

Tags: mysql

```
USE ccva1;

CREATE TABLE art_piece(
art_inventory_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
artist_id INT(11) NOT NULL, 
gallery_id INT(11) NOT NULL, 
art_collection VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
art_genre VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL, 
art_title VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL, 
art_medium VARCHAR(50)NOT NULL, 
art_acquired VARCHAR(200)NOT NULL,
art_date_acquired INT(10)NOT NULL, 
art_appraisal_value VARCHAR(20), 
art_size_inches VARCHAR(65),
art_size_centimeters VARCHAR(50), 
art_image VARCHAR(500)NOT NULL, 
art_modified_by VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
art_modified_date VARCHAR(30),
INDEX art_piece_ind(artist_id), 
FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) 
REFERENCES artist(artist_id) 
ON DELETE CASCADE, 
INDEX art_piece1_ind(gallery_id), 
FOREIGN KEY (gallery_id)
REFERENCES gallery(gallery_id) 
ON DELETE CASCADE,
INDEX art_piece2_ind(artist_id), 
FOREIGN KEY (art_modified_by) 
REFERENCES admin(admin_user_name) 
ON DELETE CASCADE )
ENGINE = INNODB;




CREATE TABLE art_exhibition(exhibition_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
gallery_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
exhibition_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
exhibition_date VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
exhibition_time VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
exhibition_description VARCHAR(3000) NOT NULL, 
exhibition_image VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
exhibition_modified_by VARCHAR(30)NOT NULL, 
exhibition_modified_date VARCHAR(30),
INDEX gal_ind(gallery_id),
FOREIGN KEY (gallery_id) 
REFERENCES gallery(gallery_id),
INDEX artist_ind(artist_id),
FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) 
REFERENCES artist(artist_id),
CONSTRAINT admin_unique UNIQUE (admin_user_name)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a column called `artist_id` in `art_exhibition`.

Assuming you have a table called `artist`, define a column with the appropriate type, which is presumably `int`, before defining the foreign key constraint.

Comment: CREATE TABLE artist(artist_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
artist_last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
artist_first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
artist_bio VARCHAR(500), 
artist_modified_by VARCHAR(30)NOT NULL, 
artist_modified_date VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT FK_artist_ind FOREIGN KEY (artist_modified_by)     
    REFERENCES admin(admin_user_name)     
  ON DELETE CASCADE    
    ON UPDATE CASCADE );

Comment: CREATE TABLE art_exhibition(exhibition_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
gallery_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
exhibition_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
exhibition_date VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
exhibition_time VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
exhibition_description VARCHAR(3000) NOT NULL, 
exhibition_image VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
exhibition_modified_by VARCHAR(30)NOT NULL, 
exhibition_modified_date VARCHAR(30),
INDEX gal_ind(gallery_id),
FOREIGN KEY (gallery_id) 
REFERENCES gallery(gallery_id),
CONSTRAINT admin_unique UNIQUE (admin_user_name)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

Comment: Sorry about that. I have fixed it and forgot to take that off.